# Embedded GeoWebCache in active cluster with shared data_dir

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have 7 instances of GeoServer with active JMS Master/Slave p2p cluster setup and data_dir shared by NFS on RHEL 7 machines with XFS over LVM. I want use embedded GeoWebCache and encountering, I suppose, synchronization issues: after publishing new sql-view layer some of instances threw exceptions

```
2019-04-05 00:50:49,650 WARN [platform.resource] - Failed to rename file resource gwc-layers/LayerInfoImpl--1d7ef2f_169ea383aa3_-7fe9.xml.tmp to gwc-layers/LayerInfoImpl--1d7ef2f_169ea383aa3_-7fe9.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '/DATA_DIR/gwc-layers/LayerInfoImpl--1d7ef2f_169ea383aa3_-7fe9.xml.tmp' does not exist
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.moveFile(FileUtils.java:2995)
        at org.geoserver.util.IOUtils.rename(IOUtils.java:530)
....

2019-04-05 00:50:49,668 ERROR [gwc.layer] - Error saving tile layer 'layer_name_here'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: TileLayer with same name already exists: layer_name_here: <LayerInfoImpl--1d7ef2f:169ea383aa3:-7fe9>
        at org.geoserver.gwc.layer.DefaultTileLayerCatalog.save(DefaultTileLayerCatalog.java:210)
```

And other instances throws

```
2019-03-21 14:31:09,172 ERROR [config.impl] - Error occurred processing a configuration change listener
org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogException: Error persisting GeoServerInfoImpl[null] to global.xml
        at org.geoserver.config.GeoServerConfigPersister.persist(GeoServerConfigPersister.java:614)
```

It's all looks like locking/synchroniation issues. I tried to set "Global locking" in GeoWebCache and then "NIO" in Global GeoServer settings, also adding

```
<lockProvider>nioLock</lockProvider>
```

into /DATA_DIR/gwc/geowebcache.xml with no luck. 
NFS mounted on clients as

```
rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=X.X.X.X,local_lock=none,addr=Y.Y.Y.Y
```

And exported on main server with options

```
rw,sync,fsid=0
```

But I also tried to mount with noac,nocto,noatime (and combinations) - some exceptions just changes to, e.g. "Stale file handle", still not working. 
I also have enabled disc quota via JDBC (PostgreSQL). 
So - how can I get working clustered embedded GeoWebCache with shared data_dir on JMS cluster of GeoServer?